# How to show the last article in a different way in my blog?

Tags: loop

I am working on a blog area in wordpress (a theme of my own) and I would like to highlight an article or show the most recent article in a different way. What function should I call? Could someone give me some reference?

[image]

Comment: Nothin, I wanted to try to do it with php, but I have no idea how, I know basic php.

Comment: please check this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-grid/